# Is the "cfgrid form field is corrupt" error after submit solved for HTML-type cfgrids in Adobe Coldfusion 11?

Tags: coldfusion, adobe, coldfusion-11

I'm using `cfgrid` with `format="html"` to edit data after submission on Adobe's [coldfusion-11](/questions/tagged/coldfusion-11) Update 4 (11,0,04,293328) and jQuery 1.8.3 (on [java](/questions/tagged/java) version 1.7.0_55 on IIS7 on Windows Server 2008 R2 64bit) and get a "submitted cfgrid form field is corrupt" error using the below `cfform` and `cfgrid` code, with these details:

```
 The submitted cfgrid form field is corrupt (name:
 __CFGRID__AFORM__OneGrid value:
 ,__CFGRID__EDIT__=4�field1�Y�field2�Y�field3�Y�is_expected�Y
 �1�U�Detail 1�Detail 1�Category 3�Details, details, details�D
 etails, details, details�No�No) 
ColdFusion cannot determine the line of the template that caused this
error. This is often caused by an error in the exception handling
subsystem.
```

The [coldfusion](/questions/tagged/coldfusion) source code is:

```
<cfform name="aform" action="" method="post">
    <cfgrid name="OneGrid"
        query="rsDetails"
        format="html"
        selectmode="edit"
        selectcolor="blue"
        insert="true"
        insertbutton="Click here to insert"
        delete="true"
        deletebutton="Click here to delete"
        colheaderbold="true"
        bgcolor="##E3F2FF"
        striperowcolor="##BDE0FF"
        striperows="true"
        rowHeight="20"
    >
    <cfgridcolumn name="field1" type="combobox"
        header="Field 1"
        width="200"
        valuesdelimiter=","
        values="#lstField1Values#"
        valuesdisplay="#lstField1Values#" select="true" >
    <cfgridcolumn name="field2" type="combobox"
        header="Field 2"
        width="150"
        valuesdelimiter=","
        values="#lstField2Values#"
        valuesdisplay="#lstField2Values#"
    >
    <cfgridcolumn
        name="field3"
        header="Field 3**"
        type="string_noCase"
        width="300">
    <cfgridcolumn name="is_expected" type="Boolean"
        header="Is this what you expected?"
        width="50"
    >
    </cfgrid>
</cfform>
```

This error has been reported [by other developers here (last update on March 13th)](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3842284), but as one can see, no response by [adobe](/questions/tagged/adobe) has been given.
Has anybody found a solution?

Comment: This is a bug in CF11 U4 onwards. There is no workaround for it.

Comment: That being the case @alesscor be sure to add your vote and/or notes to the bug you referenced.  Hopefully that will help prioritize the issue for Anit and his team.

Comment: That's correct. As of now, the fix is targeted for next update of CF11. However, if you need a hotfix prior to that, then you need a Support Contract for the same. You can reach out to us then at cfinstal<AT>adobe<DOT>com OR cf<DOT>install<AT>adobe<DOT>com

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions Miguel and Anit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few days ago I found that Jamie Martin [reported on June 25, 2015](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3842284) that [adobe](/questions/tagged/adobe) has mailing out fixes to individuals about this fix. I've not tried it yet but instead replaced the server-side [cfgrid](/questions/tagged/cfgrid) with a client-side solution: [jqgrid](/questions/tagged/jqgrid). Here comes Jamie's report:

---

«

Seems Adobe is mailing out fixes to individuals. I received a fix (some data redacted due to security). Would be nice if they'd just make the fix public at this point.

### Adobe response follows

We have got a new fix for the cfgrid issues, you are facing. This fix covers Bug# 3842284 (The submitted cfgrid form field is corrupt), Bug# 3945554 (cfgridupdate) and Bug# 3741324 (dropdown listbox outside the confines of the grid control). You can apply CF11 Update 5 first and then this fix on top of it. Please try the following steps:-

1. Stop ColdFusion 11 Application Service
2. Download the hotfix from ftp://XXXXXXXX@sjftp.adobe.com/ColdFusion/hf1100-3842284.jar. Alternatively, you can download the fix from https://www.dropbox.com/s/XXXXXXX/hf1100-3842284.jar as well.
3. Place this hf1100-3842284.jar at the location -- \ColdFusion11\cfusion\lib\updates\
4. Take a backup of cfgrid.js at \CFIDE\scripts\ajax\package\ and delete it.
5. Download the cfgrid.js from ftp://XXXXXXXXX@sjftp.adobe.com/ColdFusion/cfgrid.js and place it at the above location. Alternatively, you can download the fix from https://www.dropbox.com/s/XXXXXXXX/cfgrid.js, as well.
6. Start ColdFusion 11 Application Service.

»

Answer (score 0):

Remove CF delimiters <, ;> from the CFGRID data.  It worked for me. TIP: Reformat date data.